# Is there a quick way to generate "property grid" / Admin pages for editable grids of db tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Looking to throw together a quick back end for a php database driven app. Codeigniter was used for a php framework. I am wondering if there is a a simple plugin that will generate "editable" tables for specified db tables...does this exist?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in CodeIgniter 'scaffolding' feature (see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/scaffolding.html). This essentially allows CodeIgnter to open selected tables in your pages and allows you to add and edit data.
This Should only be used in development though, never on production,  as your opening your database tables to users!

Comment: its an interesting feature i hadn't noticed before and almost meets my needs...but i was hoping for something a little more robust to provide as a "backend" for administrator users of the app..